# How can I check the iframe on my website is secure or not?

Tags: web-application, appsec, html

My website has an iframe used for loading my client's websites (only 5).How can I make sure the iframe is secure? Also by editing `iframe src` It allows to load any other websites.How can I prevent it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to prevent? What do you mean by "editing iframe src"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to dictate how a client chooses to execute the HTML/JavaScript you provide.  **This should never be a security concern.**  If you are loading this `iframe src` based on a GET variable,  then this is XSS: `http://site?iframe_src=javascript:alert(document.cookie)`.  In this condition an attacker can introduce JavaScript into another user's session, and this is a **serious** security concern.

If a site can be placed within an iframe,  then it is vulnerable to [ClickJacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).  This does not expose the parent site that hosts the iframe,  but rather any site is subject to this type of manipulation.  There are [ways of mitigating ClickJacking for sites that must be frame-able](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#window.confirm.28.29_Protection).

Comment: OMG. When I checked that, I got javascript pop up.How Can I block it?

Comment: @make sure the url is on a whitelist.

Comment: Could you please explain little more?

Comment: @so you have a GET variable `iframe_src`, seeing as HTTP variables are attacker controlled and the basis of 99.9999999999999999% of all web app vulnerabilities this should be a concern.  Before you write this variable to the page,  make sure it is a url you trust. **Done!**